# How do I load cl-opengl and lispbuilder-sdl-image automatically at emacs startup?

Tags: opengl, emacs, sdl, slime, sbcl

How do I load cl-opengl and lispbuilder-sdl-image automatically at emacs startup?
now i have to slime-compile-load these commands in emacs at startup to use cl-opengl and image:
(asdf:load-system :cl-opengl)
(asdf:load-system :cl-glu)
(asdf:load-system :cl-glut)
(asdf:load-system :cl-glut-examples)
(asdf:load-system :lispbuilder-sdl-image)

because when i put in .emacs i get error message below and emacs starts with white interface(normally black):
Symbol's function definition is void: asdf:load-systemSymbol's function definition is void: asdf:load-system

Answer (score 0):

Emacs doesn't run common lisp. If what you want to do is load them when you start common lisp check your distribution's documentation. In the case of sbcl just put the expresions inside of the file .sbclrc in your home directory. Althought I would recommend using quicklisp to fetch the packages for you. So ql:quickload instead of asdf:load-system